# Remote image not loading

Tags: graphics, context

I am trying to insert a remote image into a pdf but although the image is available, Context cannot insert it into the document. I just have a grey square in place of the image.

Here is a MWE:

```
\starttext    

\startsection[
  title=Digits 0-10]

\startsubsection[title=0]

\tfd{Hose}
\externalfigure[https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg][width=2cm]
\stopsubsection

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Update to @aditya questions:
Context version: current version: 2017.03.02 22:23
Curl: installed
Output:

```
graphics        > inclusion > using locations 'local,global'
graphics        > inclusion > using paths '. .. ../..'
resolvers       > schemes > hashing 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg' to 'https-cdn-vectorstock-com-i-thumb-large-48-82-green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg'
resolvers       > schemes > fetching 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg', protocol 'https', method 'curl'
JFIFHHhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0-Exiv2"> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <dc:creator> <rdf:Seq> <rdf:li>VectorStock.com/15644882</rdf:li> </rdf:Seq> </dc:creator> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <?xpacket end="w"?>C











C
        D
!1AQaq#2BRbCSrDc$%4!1AQaq2R#b34BCr
                                  ?S@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ALd gePQ²MS<te*Dy&J8A^mE3֊jۮWbM8&KN<G5OX꛴0ufx4v+Vso*H.$#`tqˮu<G[i[[KN+I{ǣw{|gKGc+د5=#Ž~^^&)sSGQK3'{A^>-N8ˆό2bcx\)P =ehҐt*qlCޑ
H*쳗PT1G<3P
=F̝
 liM[YkD-3ӓYyֳ޾o/4)$dva
                       z:ςwOZ7\                fxH=ócXofkjZRH0|xǂ7&&iG-j촕X#)q2yOV]w[+*%m,hW&yn?ddn#;ܞ>Sٍ֟e[c\ek]Y#5ku;iORJHϒKGǢvO4[TlUiQ
                                                                                                                                         0^n>YZWsV"nqz7Z
            n
             "li!lDg%j+gzplrwõ>$n'Oܗgi =T=t41Բ2LĔwu6*z|shVMup8%ڽ!sZwzmh*7
                                                                         -d+m xԨ٥       \pU]G
KZt"]2<\ZV=";2j{<M%#X;h"->FMqy
yGQ˲WIl:WLČ8vm;#o_vM)'Oǡ^޾u
                           gRզFu;:IsKag'SZ?S%K[j˖k$jKvr($:Æ9`#?|4v\mUSp 5GDLGD^RǸ}!DnՅ?jj48t$k<9t[wJ;tM[-8iᦥa@֏<R
88 {uzp9?x%K=fLU=rOKVt<y҂[od73Kg'ܪ?x+S8=un
                                          /df%}Zkc5j$h?IP]bYf5Q\EԿ;^IMGz:fu5'o*c6kV٧|YޫknVwM(Yw%kk2L/
3GDMY;W$.qo;~{ZY\t7my.}fYϚOe[B:pLa,jw=ٶ,F97|V߿Z<[Mx}Cç"CЮ
                                                         WU^IsDevSj8Y#y.7zORjFW4+h-~eyYMQ3~>dǎ
*)82?<'qNK~ԏaД5D=+~49xƺ־=#O޸9{B9}Q{r<NV]v~-/t-ZgwB[DrI`TS7iYSfJy
                                                                 ˊ[13#k{cyۃ1-L,JjX\XI*۶
]?Rpw\GX^Q83N>qV;[FQFw[%h=)ώ13,EQI.hqw,.aUVmKAڶ6mnkE}Ioadaj5^MMuֺkΤj8
                                                                     :*j{o)QdʷJC_5oю[cuGV:5:W#[>>
缴?9eo)Zjnoc궾RcrZ>24%D,Y{yPS
tIdֳ]ѺiڢQ-bX]ry!>&-5vx'Hz'r>k_lsl= 9Kx,9gm=lUhmn"hcғS躏E4
/;-mz%ScQ`IafV{}IH]QRCd@ںy$nALkOHEֳB5SjuQuAqq-#/9SO{7m>$`CySQr=m
                                                                [USKKRc/r8Ó_cKCZ:12    ou}M؇p*H,䨖os\xT{J7SGFwx*LDmU;G
                                                                                                                        Z'M%AcM;sT[/OM%T8ےzL,QHE)d/$vUgjd6Dec,O>Մ2V!V&ccPw$f~glAa70Zy,s|{G/YBT_k\CcL`1_mDǜ
XعIkc?T]iMTZ)~cN!nrJ!$-ZRfRУly)ĩ`?@tAfvȰ^
                                          uOcvZI[Bִ
                                                   gʛ[ixD{]o`p;
)GyQ=>USvE,1dv
               sdTDѥKK\cu-vf;<dc1_Lx~h)}MM;˥nFÍ%c       ~3Q/Iّz44       A-+4Ҟ1A3`nk]g4%b:NZoς8giYǣya^Xq)Re]&(Z\sfd1wܱ_t@IW'.\Y=#9VG
                                                                                                                                   Oo
mhoT淘ʹD緘
9c`㜯^tOF=f",OG%cGQy,Wz{cyo識wWkM}b|հuy]';efNĴc/^h.adXZ#+6O     ⍱F-4IӰ`ulv3Mdخtrݨ⒖
                                         tO     Rci覫H>!mz-jw6m3CvxB'T?0p{Voh>м揔]hoec
                                                                                      Ê/Vrg۬\t؎jW)}%"]I{nc
                                                                                                          #6oklrpkX$;bvG%[J
OʹL|>                                                                                                                      Xgs[Ʌ-ƣG}
     ^^MUkA&gn6+fuWQ^ig;۴{ǟ
                           mj|s4x"QsUԽSH^Iq(^Y+v]|>MSjW
&PtXĒO+rw乤OLy=008LN~VH<ĸg{˸2'5<-_e}I                  ]yoGn8siQroy3G2iMˤGU${6Smn
#}e<61oiAr=;Ď(mƚiˬ,X9SxHs<,DC^RFw#ptO>TcZU8|N_&ԚPUuG-^meg{kMTN$ۤ,ݐ1TJ7N-rC~So4`^m^?/l~^<{u<mR]j(lԴ펑a\3ܴc=uF(a6X9f/[_nAT<Phmxe
                                                                                                                              NE^0َ;f(ߧvPy^f
8Zw5^M9
       P,#L'4PؘIgF޼)mmgvqa^nnR\'a       kF~xg
dOkumv=:Fre                                  i?ogޮAk=aK-$ۨ>}3i6uahѶlR߶b:9
92QA6W51yar:zݧ˷:CG+}Ƀ'z8c⸬~fD_)IXJO|Vunqɬn=$X7lv_AD߯M<g <Wg䷫ms|K쬘7VBmӻGUզku~ߥ۬
P=gһҷˋlB*I]>k~m)Θ9I+:[hSqxa.>m[zז<ce[$lTueƣ#@t]Ḹ}&+ɭb7B7{15Xfs3q!Mけqg          a$h\SShTfܕMcn/ϊ~WzGYƨ-w]lQI{N
                                                                      k{W
                                                                         nPesolvers       > schemes > using missing 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg', protocol 'https'
graphics        > inclusion > unknown url 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg'
```

Comment: I can retrieve graphics via `http://` but not `https://`.

Comment: OK. Something clearly went wrong. It appears that the jpeg file is written to STDOUT rather than the cache. 1. Can you check if you have write permissions on `TEXMFCACHE` (you can find out the directory by running `luatools --expand-var TEXMFCACHE`). 2. Does running `curl` from commnad line work correctly? In particular, does `curl --silent --insecure --create-dirs --output /tmp/file.jpg https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg` create `/tmp/file.jpg` file?

Comment: @Aditya: I do have write permissions in `TEXMFCACHE`. Running curl saves the image to `/tmp/file.jpg`

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. For some strange reasons, `curl` is writing file to STDOUT rather than to the specified file. If the image is also available via `http`, you can switch to `http` and everything should work because `http` is processed via Lua Socket library. If you do need `https` then you can try updating ConTeXt installation and see if that helps (because the example works at my end with the latest ConTeXt). If not, I can try to create a wrapper using `filter` module, a la [placekitten](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/tag/placekitten/)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but it contains more information than can be conveyed in a comment.

1. Which version of ConTeXt are you using?
2. https files are retrieved using `curl`. Do you have `curl` installed?
3. You can get better idea of what is happening by running:

   ```
   context --trackers=graphics.locating,resolvers.schemes --directives=schemes.threshold=0 --once test
   ```

On my system, this gives

```
resolvers       > schemes > hashing 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg' to 'https-cdn-vectorstock-com-i-thumb-large-48-82-green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg'
resolvers       > schemes > fetching 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg', protocol 'https', method 'curl'    
resolvers       > schemes > using cached 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg', protocol 'https', cachename '/home/adityam/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/schemes/https-cdn-vectorstock-com-i-thumb-large-48-82-green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg'    
graphics        > inclusion > file '/home/adityam/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/schemes/https-cdn-vectorstock-com-i-thumb-large-48-82-green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg' has format 'jpg'    
graphics        > inclusion > url 'https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/thumb-large/48/82/green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg' is resolved to '/home/adityam/texmf-cache/luatex-cache/context/5fe67e0bfe781ce0dde776fb1556f32e/schemes/https-cdn-vectorstock-com-i-thumb-large-48-82-green-garden-hose-agriculture-tool-cartoon-vector-15644882.jpg'    
graphics        > inclusion > format 'jpg' natively supported by backend
```

As the second line above shows, the file is being fetched using `curl`. The flag `--directives=schemes.threshold=0` is to force a download of a file (normally a file is cached and redownloaded only if the cache is more than a day old).

Comment: updated question to answer your questions.